# Computer freezes regulary and the "hardware disconnect" sound is played

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a very annoying issue. A couple of weeks now I am experiencing freezes which are directly followed (or vice versa) by a hardware disconnect sound that occurs when unplugging a usb drive or any other plug and play device.

Is there a way to debug that? I've checked the Event Logs but nothing suspicious. I've downloaded the hardware detection code from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119168/Hardware-Change-Detection but it fails to even detect usb drives changes.

It happens mainly during gaming but also while surfing websites like I've experienced it minutes ago.

I don't want to randomly update drivers, I rather want to locate the issue precisely. I've disabled all peripherals like Wifi-, and Firewire-card. Windows and nvidia are up to date.

I am trying to get a etl/wpr file via Windows Performance Recorder with the following settings:

- First Level Triage
- CPU usage
- Disk IO usage
- File IO usage
- Networking IO activity
- Audio glitches (as during games the sound stuttered during these events)

Any more?
Prior to that I had an etl/wpr file pointing to a firewire system file that caused a peak. From then I've disabled the firewire hardware (no updates were available and the firewire hardware is a very popular one). The issue still occurs but much less often.

I've unplugged all peripherals to check whether it went away, even mouse and keyboard.

I'm inclined to debug this on the lowest level even if I have not so much experience analysing etl/wpr files.

Comment: In my experience this is frequently a hard drive failure.  However, you should use a temperature monitoring software like **speedfan** or whatever comes with your motherboard to monitor temperatures and voltages.  Voltages should be within 5% + or - of the stated voltage.  You need a graphing software so you can launch your game play it, exit the game and check the number when the system was under load.  Also if the setting exists set the sampling interval to 1 second.

Comment: Well, speedfan says that via SMART all my disks are ok, voltage looks good too. The etl file however shows some IO on my SSD shortly before the sound system issues the hardware disconnected sound

Comment: How about your temperatures? Have you upgraded the firmware on your SSD? Stress test your CPU with prime95 http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=205

Comment: I've located the issue. It is a broken cord of my mouse. Which is really strange as I've replaced it with a spare mouse during my tests and I was sure that I've had the same issue...